# Sharepoint 2013 rotate image and save to list

Tags: jquery, image, sharepoint

I created a page with a form were users can submit some data to a list and upload a file to save on that list as an attachment. 
I also give the users the possibility to rotate the image that they upload before saveit to that list.
My problem is that a cant save the rotated image, only the original one the was uploded

Code for the upload

```
    <td>
        <label>Picture</label>
        <input type="file" onchange="readURL(this)" class="form-control-file" id="Picture">
    </td>
```

Code to display the file on page

```
    function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(80)
                .height(100);
            };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Code to rotate image

```
$('.button').on("click", function(e) {
    quantosrodou = quantosrodou + 90;
    if (quantosrodou == 360){
        quantosrodou = 0;
    }
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).is("#left")) {
        deg = deg - 90;
    } else {
        deg = deg + 90;
    }
$("#blah").css({
    "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + deg + "deg)",
    "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + deg + "deg)",
    transform: "rotate(" + deg + "deg)"
});
```

});

If you guys can help me I really appreciate

Comment: Is this a iOS issue? I had the same problem with all iOS devices. Maybe you should look into rotating the image server side. Otherwise you would need to operate on the 'file' leve in JS instead of the dom/html.

Comment: Have you considered using workflows? Check the "Rotate Image" action here: https://www.harepoint.com/Products/HarePointWorkflowExtensions/Images-SharePoint-Workflow-Action.aspx